# How to Remove Opacity of Background on Clicking Show More Button

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a user story with only the first 4 lines shown. The 4th line is faded with a Show More button underneath. On pressing the Show More (and Show Less) button I would like to remove the opacity and show the story. Showing the story is fine, but I'm struggling to remove and reply the opacity to the 4th line.  I use an ::after pseudo element to apply the fading effect and I cannot access this using jQuery... any advice please?

Fiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/znoack8y/)

```
/*JQuery*/

<script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".content").on("click", '.showMore', function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    var content = $this.prev()
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();
    
    if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
      linkText = "Show less";
      $this.siblings('div').css('height', 'auto');
      var currHeight = $this.siblings('div').height();
       $this.siblings('div').css('height', '8em');
       $this.siblings('div').animate({height: currHeight}, 500);
    } else {
       $this.siblings('div').animate({height: '8em'}, 500);
      linkText = "Show more";
    }

    $this.text(linkText);
  
  });

});

/*CSS*/

.post-text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 6em;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white);
}

.post-text{
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Times, serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: justify;
}

.hideContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 8em;
}

.showContent {
  line-height: 1em;
  height: auto;
}

.showMore {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1ca099;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/*Html*/

<div class="content">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="hideContent">
        <div class="post-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam blandit a ipsum nec pharetra. Donec eget tempus neque. Vestibulum sit amet sollicitudin ligula. Sed viverra odio nec augue fermentum condimentum. Etiam dapibus urna sit amet sagittis lobortis. Maecenas ut nisi et leo facilisis pellentesque. Pellentesque sed lacus nulla. Morbi auctor quam et neque fermentum, quis congue erat viverra. Aliquam aliquam vulputate lorem, euismod scelerisque augue finibus eu. Suspendisse efficitur bibendum nibh, blandit finibus sapien eleifend a. Vestibulum bibendum augue augue, nec dictum nisi posuere a.
       </div>
    </div>
  <div class="showMore"><a>Show more</a></div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to target the pseudo elements such as `:after` in jQuery.

However there is a workaround you can use. You ca set up another, ***more specific***, rule in your CSS using an additional class, and this rule will remove the css, e.g.

```
.fullpost .post-text::after {
    height:0;          /* remove the height or the element still exists! */
    background: none;  /* remove the white gradient background */
}
```

Note the CSS specificity is the important part here! Because we are using a more specific CSS selector, it will override the rule for `.post-text::after`. If we add the `fullpost` class to any ancestor of the `post-text` class, this rule will now override the existing rule and set the background to none.

**Note**: We also set `height:0` because otherwise the invisible element is still positioned over the text and could affect things like trying to select the text underneath it for example. (This would generally work on its own, but we can remove the white overlay also if you want to be sure! )

Now in your jQuery, you add the class to the parent div when you click "Show More":

```
if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
    $this.parent('div').addClass('fullpost');
    /* rest of your code here... */
}
```

and remove it for "show less":

```
} else {
   $this.parent('div').removeClass('fullpost');
    /* rest of your code here... */
}
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".content").on("click", '.showMore', function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    var content = $this.prev()
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();
    
    if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
      linkText = "Show less";
      $this.siblings('div').css('height', 'auto');
      var currHeight = $this.siblings('div').height();
       $this.siblings('div').css('height', '8em');
       $this.siblings('div').animate({height: currHeight}, 500);
        $this.parent('div').addClass('fullpost');
   } else {
       $this.siblings('div').animate({height: '8em'}, 500);

       $this.parent('div').removeClass('fullpost');
      linkText = "Show more";
    }
    
$this.text(linkText);
  
  });

});
```

```css
.post-text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 6em;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white);
}

.fullpost .post-text::after {
  height:0;
  background: none;
}

.post-text{
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Times, serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: justify;
}

.hideContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 8em;
}

.showContent {
  line-height: 1em;
  height: auto;
}

.showMore {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1ca099;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="hideContent">
        <div class="post-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam blandit a ipsum nec pharetra. Donec eget tempus neque. Vestibulum sit amet sollicitudin ligula. Sed viverra odio nec augue fermentum condimentum. Etiam dapibus urna sit amet sagittis lobortis. Maecenas ut nisi et leo facilisis pellentesque. Pellentesque sed lacus nulla. Morbi auctor quam et neque fermentum, quis congue erat viverra. Aliquam aliquam vulputate lorem, euismod scelerisque augue finibus eu. Suspendisse efficitur bibendum nibh, blandit finibus sapien eleifend a. Vestibulum bibendum augue augue, nec dictum nisi posuere a.
       </div>
    </div>
  <div class="showMore"><a>Show more</a></div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great and really well explained. When pressing the show less button is there a way of applying the fade to the 4th line after the excess rows have been hidden, apposed to before?

Answer (score 2):

You can't manipulate :after, because it's not technically part of the DOM and therefore is inaccessible by any JavaScript. But you can add a new class with a new :after specified. You have to do it by toggle class.

fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/g21793nq/

Use this css :

```
.post-text.changed:after{
  background:none;
}
```

Js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".content").on("click", '.showMore', function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    var content = $this.prev()
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();
    
    if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
      linkText = "Show less";
      $('.post-text').toggleClass('changed');
      $this.siblings('div').css('height', 'auto');
      var currHeight = $this.siblings('div').height();
       $this.siblings('div').css('height', '8em');
       $this.siblings('div').animate({height: currHeight}, 500);
    } else {
     $('.post-text').toggleClass('changed');
       $this.siblings('div').animate({height: '8em'}, 500);
      linkText = "Show more";
    }

    $this.text(linkText);
  
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for posting that answer. Your fiddle doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: added running fiddle. i forgot to save. https://jsfiddle.net/g21793nq/ @CGarden

Comment: Thanks again +1. Is there an advantage between using remove class and toggle class?

Answer (score 2):

according to your implementation i am giving you a simple solution, you can find my changes here

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/xqbm2h65/1/)

i just added a modifier class to your content, given your after styling to it instead of element. and just toggled the class with your existing javascript conditions.ent

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var shortClass = "post-text--short";
  
  $(".content").on("click", '.showMore', function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $postContent = $(".content").find(".post-text");

    var content = $this.prev()
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();
    
    if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
      linkText = "Show less";
      $postContent.removeClass(shortClass);
      $this.siblings('div').css('height', 'auto');
      var currHeight = $this.siblings('div').height();
       $this.siblings('div').css('height', '8em');
       $this.siblings('div').animate({height: currHeight}, 500);
    } else {
       $this.siblings('div').animate({height: '8em'}, 500);
      linkText = "Show more";
    $postContent.addClass(shortClass);
    }

    $this.text(linkText);
  
  });

});
```

```css
.post-text--short::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 6em;
    left: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white);
}

.post-text{
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 2;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Times, serif;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;

}

.hideContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 8em;
}

.showContent {
  line-height: 1em;
  height: auto;
}

.showMore {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1ca099;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="hideContent">
        <div class="post-text post-text--short"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam blandit a ipsum nec pharetra. Donec eget tempus neque. Vestibulum sit amet sollicitudin ligula. Sed viverra odio nec augue fermentum condimentum. Etiam dapibus urna sit amet sagittis lobortis. Maecenas ut nisi et leo facilisis pellentesque. Pellentesque sed lacus nulla. Morbi auctor quam et neque fermentum, quis congue erat viverra. Aliquam aliquam vulputate lorem, euismod scelerisque augue finibus eu. Suspendisse efficitur bibendum nibh, blandit finibus sapien eleifend a. Vestibulum bibendum augue augue, nec dictum nisi posuere a.
       </div>
    </div>
  <div class="showMore"><a>Show more</a></div>

   </div>
</div>
```