# Inserting ::after inside jquery element

Tags: html, jquery, css

How do i add an ::after element inside another element

so i have:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdowncomp" href="#/" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:16px;">          "Dropdown"        </a>
```

How do i add the ::after element so it ends up like this in jquery:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdowncomp" href="#/" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:16px;">          "Dropdown"        

::after

</a>
```

i tried:

```
            $($(getTab()).find(".iframeclass").contents().find("#" + idLink).children(0)).append("::after");
```

Comment: Do you really want to add the literal text `::after`, or do you want the CSS pseudu-element?

Comment: Pseudo-elements aren't separate things you can add to the DOM. You simply refer to them in CSS, and the browser displays them automatically.

Comment: You can't access them with jQuery, either, since they're not separate DOM elements. They're just part of the style of the main element.

Comment: you can toggle class using jQuery and with help of css add pseudu-element. Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63640189/how-to-remove-opacity-of-background-on-clicking-show-more-button/63640274#63640274